# Number of compositions, does this sequence have a closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does this sequence have a closed form:

1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 14, 25, 46, 87, 167, 324, 634, 1248, 2466, 4887, 9706, 19308, 38455, 76659, 152925, 305232, 609488, 1217429, 2432399, 4860881, 9715511, 19421029, 38826059,...

http://oeis.org/A177510

It turns up as the first column in a lower triangular matrix in which the row sums give the number of divisors of n.

Comment: You should explain the restrictions on the compositions being counted here.  The sequence is 0-based, so the first entry counts certain compositions of zero (easy!); the $n+1$st entry counts some compositions of $n$.  However the compositions of $n = \sum_{i=0}^k p_i$ seem to have two restrictions: $p_0$ is less than or equal to any other summand, and the difference $p_i - p_0$ is less than or equal to $i$.